# how to cancel job in Dolphindb

Tags: database, dolphindb

I use the function of submitJob to get the `jobId` and I try to cancel the job by using the cancelJob function, but I failed to stop the job. What function should I use to stop the job?
I use the code below:
submitJob("aa", "a1", replay, [ds], [`sink],` date, `time, 10)
cancelJob(aa)

Answer (score 0):

The function `submitJob` will return the actual jobId that might be different from the input jobId. So please use the jobId returned by the `submitJob` function.

DolphinDB uses thread pool to run jobs. So if the job is simple and contains no sub tasks, we still can't cancel the job.